# Cocos2D-X most efficient way to select the appropriate sprite sheet

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x, sprite-sheet

I have 3 sets of sprite sheets for my first scene. 
I'm using XCode to develop for iOS using Cocos2D-X.

The first sprite sheet has an extension -sd, 
the second sprite sheet has -hd, 
and the third set has 3 sprite sheets (using Multipack in Texture Packer Pro) with the extension -ipadhd.
I followed a tutorial and I found a method that goes like this

```
CCString* file = (Utils::getArtScaleFactor() > 1) ? CCString::create("randomFile-hd.plist") : CCString::create("randomFile-sd.plist");

//The Utils::getArtScaleFactor function
float Utils::getArtScaleFactor()
{
    return artScaleFactor;
}
```

1- Is there a similar way to choose between 3 files instead of 2?

2- Is this the common method for choosing the appropriate file size-wise?

3- This question is somewhat off the topic I was discussing but I really need an answer to it too: I have an animation and its frames are split into 3 sprite sheets, how do I cache 3 .plist files? And if that's impossible, what are my options?

Hope I provided all the necessary information!

Regards

Comment: Where did you get Utils::getArtScaleFactor from? It's not in my Cocosd2x v3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sure, but that ternary operator should probably be switched out with another construct (like a switch) for clarity and flexibility.

   For example:

   ```
   // Always init your pointers.
   CCString* file = NULL;

   switch (Utils::getArtScaleFactor()) 
   {
     // Scale factor shouldn't ever be 0, but we should account for it 
     // so it doesn't get picked up by the default case.
     case 0:
     case 1:
       file = CCString::create("randomFile-sd.plist");
       break;

     case 2:
       file = CCString::create("randomFile-hd.plist");
       break;

     // Scale factors 3 and above get the largest resource.
     default:
       file = CCString::create("randomFile-super-hd.plist");
       break;
   }
   ```
2. Yes, this type of logic is on the [wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support#designResolutionSize), except they use if-else for three resource sizes. I've seen it on the forums and tutorials, too.
3. According to [this thread](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/animation-loading-and-animating-multiple-spritesheets) on the cocos2d-iphone forums, **yes**:

> CCSprite can display CCSpriteFrames with different textures.
>     So there’s no problem at all even to use animation that mixes frames from different textures (spritesheets) - [Stepan Generalov](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/animation-loading-and-animating-multiple-spritesheets/#post-296222)

The [implementations posted there](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/animation-loading-and-animating-multiple-spritesheets/#post-296219) are in obj-c but you can convert the cocos2d api calls to cpp easily.

Comment: Well this answers all my questions!
Thank you so much for the neat and straight-forward answers! :)